# How do I create AWS Neptune nodes with nested proprieties using gremlin queries

Tags: amazon-web-services, gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune

I'm looking into a way to create nodes with nested proprieties like the "location" inside this example, that I found on Github here: https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/master/data/tinkerpop-crew.json

```
{
  "id":{
    "@type":"g:Int32",
    "@value":1
  },
  "label":"person",
  "properties":{
    "location":[
      {
        "id":{
          "@type":"g:Int64",
          "@value":6
        },
        "value":"san diego",
        "properties":{
          "startTime":{
            "@type":"g:Int32",
            "@value":1997
          },
          "endTime":{
            "@type":"g:Int32",
            "@value":2001
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "id":{
          "@type":"g:Int64",
          "@value":7
        },
        "value":"santa cruz",
        "properties":{
          "startTime":{
            "@type":"g:Int32",
            "@value":2001
          },
          "endTime":{
            "@type":"g:Int32",
            "@value":2004
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "id":{
          "@type":"g:Int64",
          "@value":8
        },
        "value":"brussels",
        "properties":{
          "startTime":{
            "@type":"g:Int32",
            "@value":2004
          },
          "endTime":{
            "@type":"g:Int32",
            "@value":2005
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "id":{
          "@type":"g:Int64",
          "@value":9
        },
        "value":"santa fe",
        "properties":{
          "startTime":{
            "@type":"g:Int32",
            "@value":2005
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

[I also found in the Tinkerpop Apache documentation that vertexes can have properties on properties](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#vertex-properties)
, but I'm not understanding the documentation and how I should do that.

Any help would be appreciated

I tried following the Tinkerpop Apache documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon Neptune does not currently support "meta properties" (properties of properties). Please see [this section](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-differences.html#gremlin-api-reference-features) of the documentation:

Comment: Well, that solves it then, if it isn't supported there isn't much that I can do about it. Thank you for the help